# How to declare a custom coordinate

Tags: circuitikz, coordinates

I have created this sample diagram, where everything is aligned with the inputs of the first and gate. Would it be possible to replace these `([xshift=-15mm]bothNegated.bin 1)` with a custom expression declared previously, such that one does not have to repeat the same command over and over again?

I am using the [circuitikzgit](https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/pull/168) package for the [inverted inputs](https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/issues/166) only, the rest is just as in circuitikz.

I have tried using a node at the intersection, but then the lines `([xshift=-5mm]bothNegated.bin 1) |- node[circ,midway]{} (notB.in 1)` are not connected to the line leading into the top and gate.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikzgit}
\begin{document}
 \begin{circuitikz} \draw

(2,0) node[and port] (bothTrue) {}
(2,2) node[and port] (notB) {}
(2,4) node[and port] (notA) {}
(2,6) node[and port] (bothNegated) {}


([xshift=-15mm]bothNegated.bin 1) node[anchor=east] (Anode) {A}

([xshift=-15mm]bothNegated.bin 1) -| (bothNegated.in 1)
([xshift=-5mm]bothNegated.bin 1) node[circ]{} |-  (bothTrue.in 1) 

([xshift=-5mm]bothNegated.bin 1) |- node[circ,midway]{} (notB.in 1)
([xshift=-5mm]bothNegated.bin 1) |- node[circ,midway]{} (notA.in 1)



([xshift=-15mm]bothNegated.bin 2) node[anchor=east] {B}
([xshift=-15mm]bothNegated.bin 2) -| (bothNegated.in 2)
([xshift=-10mm]bothNegated.bin 2) node[circ]{} |-  (bothTrue.in 2)

([xshift=-10mm]bothNegated.bin 2) |- node[circ,midway]{} (notA.in 2)
([xshift=-10mm]bothNegated.bin 2) |- node[circ,midway]{} (notB.in 2)



(bothNegated.bin 2) node[ocirc, left] {}
(bothNegated.bin 1) node[ocirc, left] {}
(notA.bin 2) node[ocirc, left] {}
(notB.bin 1) node[ocirc, left] {}


;\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image: sample]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define coordinates like this:

```
\coordinate (c1) at ([xshift=-15mm]bothNegated.bin 1);
\coordinate (c2) at ([xshift=-15mm]bothNegated.bin 2);
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikzgit}
\begin{document}
 \begin{circuitikz} 
\draw
(2,0) node[and port] (bothTrue) {}
(2,2) node[and port] (notB) {}
(2,4) node[and port] (notA) {}
(2,6) node[and port] (bothNegated) {};

\coordinate (c1) at ([xshift=-15mm]bothNegated.bin 1);
\coordinate (c2) at ([xshift=-15mm]bothNegated.bin 2);

\draw
(c1) node[anchor=east] (Anode) {A}

(c1) -| (bothNegated.in 1)
([xshift=10mm]c1) node[circ]{} |-  (bothTrue.in 1) 
([xshift=10mm]c1) |- node[circ,midway]{} (notB.in 1)
([xshift=10mm]c1) |- node[circ,midway]{} (notA.in 1)

(c2) node[anchor=east] {B}
(c2) -| (bothNegated.in 2)
([xshift=5mm]c2) node[circ]{} |-  (bothTrue.in 2)

([xshift=5mm]c2) |- node[circ,midway]{} (notA.in 2)
([xshift=5mm]c2) |- node[circ,midway]{} (notB.in 2)

(bothNegated.bin 2) node[ocirc, left] {}
(bothNegated.bin 1) node[ocirc, left] {}
(notA.bin 2) node[ocirc, left] {}
(notB.bin 1) node[ocirc, left] {};
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```